# How to get / use the name of 2 widgets and use them in a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm trying to set up a function to hide ***Button1*** and to make ***Button2*** visible.

So far I can hide ***Button1*** as I've written the following code in the Script Section:

```
function nextButton(Button1) {
     Button1.visible = false;
}
```

In the OnClick event of Button1 I wrote:

```
nextButton(widget);
```

What I'm trying to do is to send Button2 to the function. I tried the following:

```
OnClick event: nextButton2(widget, Button2);
Script:  function nextButton(Button1, Button2) {
     Button1.visible = false;
     Button2.visible = true;  }
```

This way when I click on Button1 it would hide and Button2 will appear.
But it seems that sending the name of the object (**Button2**) is not working.

Do you know how I can reference another object and send it to the function?

Comment: How are you getting `Button2` when you're going to call the function? Also, in the `OnClick` event, any reason why it's `nextButton2` instead of just `nextButton`?

Comment: **Button2** is the name of that button, I assumed sending the name of the object into the function will work - It didn't. So my question is how I can build something like:

var Button2 = app.Page.button2;

To send that variable into the function. 
PD: The number 2 in the function was a typo... the name is just nextButton()

Comment: If by name you mean the ID of the button then it should be a string, as in `"Button2"` but the answer provided by @TheMaster gives you a way to get the button object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `Button2` element from the global variable [`app`](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#App).

```
var Button2 = app.pages.PageWithTheButton.Button2; //Assuming the button is directly in the page.
```